# Can TrueZip be used to seek through streams

Tags: java, truezip

Let's assume I have a large zip file on a server and I am interested in extracting just a subset from it over the HTTP. Is this possible with TrueZip and if yes, how? The idea is not to have to download the entire zip, but just the zip header, do some seeking and then extract the set of files from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, TrueZIP 7.7.3 does not support this.

However, the TrueZIP Driver HTTP(S) is only a small wrapper around the Apache HttpsClient which does support this. Furthermore, TrueZIP does provide the necessary interface logic (which is used by other drivers, e.g. the TrueZIP Driver ZIP). So while currently not supported, it should be possible to implement this by enhancing the current implementation of the TrueZIP Driver HTTP(S).

Answer (score 1):

What kind of server you're talking about?

If that's an HTTP server - then answer is no. You must have some server application runing that receives command to "extract just a subset". Without this you should download entire file to client and extract on client. If you're still talking about HTTP server, then you probably mean chunked file download (to seek and find a place) then probably answer would be yes, but this will require lot of analysis and coding I think.